# Cant find new reports created with OpenOffice for openerp 7

Tags: report, designer, openoffice.org, openerp-7

I've created a simple new report using OpenOffice report designer for OpenERP and I've sent it to the server, but when i looked for it on my OpenERP DB (either client interface and addons) i couldn't find it.
All the tutos on the internet don't show where to find new reports created by OpenOffice (they all stop at the "send to server" step like the official docs of OpenERP [http://openerp.co.za/7/reports/reporting.html ]
thanks in advance for your help.
PS: i am using OpenERP 7 and OpenOffice 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check a record like this and click 'Print' to fin your report
[image]